# convert string to dictionary in python (passing dict as plain str)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string

`test_string = "{Team A: [service1, service2], Team B: [service3, service4], Team 3: [service5, service6] }"`

I want to know a way to convert this into a **dictionary in python**

Comment: Tried `json.loads(test_string)`?

Comment: @shaikmoeed it's not JSON...

Comment: It's not valid JSON. Nor will `ast.literal_eval` work. At least, not with what's been shown

Comment: Convert it into _what_ dictionary? That's not valid JSON, or Python. Where does the string _come from_, could it be serialised into something that _could_ be more easily parsed?

Comment: passing this from Azure DevOps Pipeline to terraform which is gonna invoke python program

Comment: @KetanBijwe the question is not what you're going to do with it, it's how you expect to parse it. It's not valid ... anything, really. `service1` might be a string literal, it might be something else, but we have no clue.

Comment: `json.loads` and `ast.literal_eval` are both *parsers*, and your string does not meet the construction requirements of either of them.  [pyparsing](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/) can be used to construct a custom parser, if that's what you desire and can't change the string format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`yaml`](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) library is able to load this. It will turn all your items into strings, unless they are parseable in python:

```py
import yaml

test_string = "{Team A: [service1, service2], Team B: [service3, service4], Team 3: [service5, service6] }"

parsed_dict = yaml.safe_load(test_string)
print(parsed_dict)
```

Outputs:

```py
{'Team A': ['service1', 'service2'], 'Team B': ['service3', 'service4'], 'Team 3': ['service5', 'service6']}
```

---

Here is another example of what it may parse:

```py
>>> yaml.safe_load("{a b c : [123, 99.0, a string, another]}")
{'a b c': [123, 99.0, 'a string', 'another']}
```

You should be aware that YAML (and so parsing with YAML) is a very complicated format that [can have a lot of unintended effects](https://ruudvanasseldonk.com/2023/01/11/the-yaml-document-from-hell). If possible you should find out if you can output JSON or some other serialised data from your Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). There is an example on the bottom on how to use specific dictionary parts

```py
import re

test_string = "{Team A: [service1, service2], Team B: [service3, service4], Team 3: [service5, service6] }"

key_regex = r'([\w ]+):' #matches key
value_regex = r'\[([^\]]+)\]' #matches opening bracket then matches characters that are not a closing bracket and then matches closing bracket

pairs = re.findall(f'{key_regex}\s*{value_regex}', test_string) #returns all non-overlapping matches of re in test_string

dictionary = {}

for key, value in pairs:
    key = key.strip() 
    value = value.split(', ') 
    dictionary[key] = value 

print(f"Full: {dictionary}") #outputs: {'Team A': ['service1', 'service2'], 'Team B': ['service3', 'service4'], 'Team 3': ['service5', 'service6']}

print(dictionary['Team A'])  #outputs: ['service1', 'service2']
print(dictionary['Team B'])  #outputs: ['service3', 'service4']
print(dictionary['Team 3'])  #outputs: ['service5', 'service6']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to break down the string into key and value substrings.  Then build the dictionary by stripping the delimiters out and using split to convert the values to lists:

```
import re

S = "{Team A: [service1, service2], Team B: [service3, service4], Team 3: [service5, service6] }"

parts = filter(bool,re.split(r"([{,] *(?:[^,]+?:))",S))
D = {k.strip("{, :"):v.strip(" [],}").split(", ") for k,v in zip(parts,parts)}

print(D)
{'Team A': ['service1', 'service2'], 
 'Team B': ['service3', 'service4'], 
 'Team 3': ['service5', 'service6']}
```

*The `parts` variable is an iterator on the substrings that is fed to zip twice to pair up consecutive substrings into a key and value*

output of pairs (re.split with a capture group in the pattern includes separators in the output):

```
'{Team A:', ' [service1, service2]', 
', Team B:', ' [service3, service4]', 
', Team 3:', ' [service5, service6] }'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ast module

```
import ast

test_string = "{Team A: [service1, service2], Team B: [service3, service4], Team 3: [service5, service6] }"

# Wrap the string in curly braces to make it a valid dictionary literal
test_string = "{" + test_string + "}"

# Use ast.literal_eval to convert the string to a dictionary
result_dict = ast.literal_eval(test_string)

print(result_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Team A': ['service1', 'service2'], 'Team B': ['service3', 'service4'], 'Team 3': ['service5', 'service6']}
```

Note that in the original string, the dictionary keys and values are not surrounded by quotes, so they will be interpreted as variable names. the keys are converted to strings and the values are assumed to be variables that are not defined in the current scope. If you want the dictionary keys and values to be treated as strings, you should surround them with quotes in the original string.

Comment: Did you actually try this? It doesn't do what you claim it does.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: dictionary keys must be enclosed in quotes, either single or double quotes. So you should update your input string to use quotes around the keys

Comment: they will be interpreted as variable names.

Comment: service1, service2 ...must be enclosed in quotes mean  "service1"

Comment: `Team A` isn't even a valid  variable name. And you are talking about putting thing in quotes, without showing how.

Comment: this will help you understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/75725716/3894100 @gre_gor

Comment: Understand what? That your answer is completely wrong, as that string isn't valid Python code?

Answer (score -3):

You can use the eval() function to convert the string into a dictionary.

Here's an example:

```
test_string = '{"Team A": ["service1", "service2"], "Team B": ["service3", "service4"], "Team 3": ["service5", "service6"] }'

dictionary = eval(test_string)

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'Team A': ['service1', 'service2'], 'Team B': ['service3', 'service4'], 'Team 3': ['service5', 'service6']}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you even try this?  It doesn't work.

Comment: That isn't the OP's string now.

Comment: @KetanBijwe  try it again I've fix it, try it now

Comment: @MarkTolonen fixed, try it now

Comment: Again, that's not the OP's string.